# Why is ${\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{n+1}}\bigm/{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^n} \geq \frac 1n{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Why is $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{n+1}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^n} \geq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{n}$$
where $n$ is some positive natural number, and all $a_i$s are assumed to be positive real number?

Comment: This is not correct. Take $n = 2, a_1= a_2 < 1$.

Comment: Sorry. There was a typo..

Comment: Should I delete the question and start a new question, as it would be confusing? I did correct the typo, though.

Comment: this is the special case of [Chebyshev Inequality Rearrangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_sum_inequality)

Answer (score 3):

This is the special case $(r,s) = (1,n)$ of the following inequality:

**Lemma.**
*Suppose $r$, $s$, and $a_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq n$) are positive reals.  Then*
$$
n \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{r+s} \geq \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^r \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^s,
$$
*with equality* iff *the $a_i$ are all equal*.

The relation between the number $n$ of variables and the exponents $1,n$
is a red herring.

*Proof* of Lemma:
Without loss of generality $r \leq s$.  Let $x_i = a_i^s$,
and divide both sides by $n^2$, so the desired inequality becomes
$$
\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{p+1} \right)
\geq
\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p \right)
\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)
$$
where $p = r/s \leq 1$.
But the function $x \mapsto x^{p+1}$ is strictly convex upwards, so
$$
\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{p+1} \right)
\geq
\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{p+1}
$$
with equality *iff* the $x_i$ are all equal; while
$x \mapsto x^p$ is convex downwards, so
$$
\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p \right)
\leq
\left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^p
$$
with equality if the $x_i$ are all equal.
The desired result follows.$\diamondsuit$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* compare 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^n\cdot \frac{\sum_{i=1}^1a_i}{n}$$
with 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^n\cdot a_i$$